# How to add multiple post in single wordpress page as per post id

Tags: php, wordpress

I can try this code in page text but not working

```
<?php
$post_id = '138'; 
echo get_post_field('post_content', $post_id); 
?>
```

show a code only not display content, 
provide solutions in which file I can add this code.

Comment: you can use wp_query : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Where did you put the code? Inside .php files or just on a page inside wordpress. Because if you just pasted that inside your wordpress page, you won't get a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wordpress provide `insert_pages` plugin and in this plugin in page add post or another page title, content etc